# How to pronounce feel, fill, or feeling correctly?

Tags: pronunciation

I have thought that FEEL would sound  like this:[FEE-L](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10NEP4wYWTrxQT8OlA4Srnh6J2xjvfeBX)

Then I knew it sounds like FEE-ul. I understand that it is the L sound that makes it sound like vowel sound of hEAR. I’m still not clear of FILL. I have three pronunciation:[my 3 sounds of FILL](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16JCBu4Of6uKwQJ8F7rzCGi1znGGdiFkF). I think the third sound when I said FI-ul is correct. Is it right?

FEELING is also confusing. I have 4 sounds: [feeling](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kXTKxrbwBLQ2m8gIyjRUrv9WsK11Uc2C). Which is correct?
After all, I still don’t clearly understand the difference between my L sound and the English L sound:[L sounds](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1liOfYTpKfUKuEgDJIVRzDP5VSnmBnqL6)

I hope you could make it clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The speaker in your two examples is British, with the characteristic "EE" sound of that accent.  The way he pronounces both "feel" and "feeling" is greatly exaggerated, in order to allow you to hear each part clearly.  You should not try to imitate this way in natural speech.

I can't much help you with that accent, but I can say that a "standard" American accent will certainly pronounce the final "L", although not as if it was a second syllable.  FEE-ul would be too much.  End the word with your tongue pressed to the roof of your mouth, and that should be sufficient.

With "feel", You pronounce the "EE" sound fine.  Your challenge is to learn to pronounce the "L" sound as distinct from the "R" sound.  Once you get that, the word will sound more natural.  Your second recording is better, so just learn to make that same sound more quickly, with less exaggeration.

Additionally, many English speakers will blend the final "L" of a word like "feel" with any following word that starts with "L":

> I **fee'like** going to the park today.
>
> Does she **fee'lonely**?

And so on.

"Feeling" is two syllables, each of which is pronounced.  The "L" sound between the syllables can be very brief, with only a quick touch of the tongue to the roof of the mouth.

Comment: Hi, Andrew. I’d like to clarify that all of those recordings are mine, not from British speaker. I also don’t understand “two examples” since I have 4 examples. And I did lift my tongue to the roof of mouth. The problem is I don’t understand why there’s ul sound. Thanks.

Comment: @user67265  huh.  Well then in some cases your accent is pretty good.  I thought it a native.  I'm surprised the pairs of recordings sound so different to me.

Comment: Oh, I’m surprised to hear that. I gave different pronunciations for each word just to know which is correct. So could you please specify which sound in each recordings is right?

Comment: Better to show the blended words as contractions to aid pronunciation.  That would be feel'ike and feel'onely.

Comment: @EllieK  Good suggestion.  I edited my answer.